# JSON data search and bundle in Android

Tags: android, google-maps, android-json, android-bundle

Sorry for my bad English.I am new android.

I have some problem for `JSON` in Android that

(1.)I've been to obtain information from the Internet (`JSON`). How can I mark all station on googlemap on particular page?

(2.1) I've been to obtain information from the Internet(`JSON`) and show those information in the listView. This listView is composed by two `TextView`(txtV1, txtV2). How can I Use the keyword_search to filter the `ListView` by the editText?

(2.2) If I click the option, the relevant information will be transmitted to the next page and display. Now, I can only bunndle the String data. How can I bundle the (lat,lng) and mark on google map?

This is json :

```
{
  "retCode": "1",
  "retVal": [
    {
      "iid": "339",
      "sno": "0001",
      "mday": "20140711003603",
      "lat": "25.0408578889",
      "lng": "121.567904444"
    },
    {
      "iid": "340",
      "sno": "0002",
      "mday": "20140711003508",
      "lat": "25.041",
      "lng": "121.556945"
    }
  ]
}
```

**This is problem(2.1) code:**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.station);
        oslist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        new JSONParse().execute();
    }

    private class JSONParse extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {

        private ProgressDialog pDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            sna = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sna);
            ar = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ar);
        }

        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {

            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

            // Getting JSON from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
            return json;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            try {

                // Getting JSON Array from URL
                youbike = json.getJSONArray(TAG_retVal);
                for (int i = 0; i < youbike.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = youbike.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing JSON item in a Variable
                    final String iid = c.getString(TAG_iid);
                                        final String sno = c.getString(TAG_sno);
                    final String mday = c.getString(TAG_mday);
                    final String lat = c.getString(TAG_lat);
                    final String lng = c.getString(TAG_lng);

                    // Adding value HashMap key => value

                    final HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    map.clear();
                    map.put(TAG_iid, iid);
                                        map.put(TAG_sno, sno);
                    map.put(TAG_mday, mday);
                    map.put(TAG_lat, lat);
                    map.put(TAG_lng, lng);

                    oslist.add(map);
                    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(station.this,
                            oslist, R.layout.station_list, new String[] {
                                    TAG_iid, TAG_sno }, new int[] { R.id.sno,
                                    R.id.iid });
                    list.setAdapter(adapter);

                    // bundle to next page

                    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,
                                View view, int position, long id) {

                            Intent intent = new Intent();
                            intent.setClass(station.this, station_1.class);

                            Bundle b = new Bundle();

                            b.putString("TAG_iid",
                                    oslist.get(+position).get("iid"));
                            b.putString("TAG_sno",
                                    oslist.get(+position).get("sno"));
                            b.putString("TAG_mday",
                                    oslist.get(+position).get("mday"));
                            b.putString("TAG_lat",
                                    oslist.get(+position).get("lat"));
                            b.putString("TAG_lng",
                                    oslist.get(+position).get("lng"));
                            intent.putExtras(b);
                            startActivity(intent);

                        }
                    });
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: sorry I am the rookie. Can you teach me how to post Logcat? Do you want to see the "system.out.println" information about what I show on the listview(txt1,txt2)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To filter your results, take a look at [SimpleAdapter#getFilter()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.html#getFilter()). Example:

```
private void filterResults(CharSequence filterText){
    Filter filter = mSimpleAdapter.getFilter();
    filter.filter(filterText);
}
...
mSearchBox.addTextChangeListener(new TextWatcher(){
    ...
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            filterResults(s);
        }
});
```

To pass lat/long trough `Bundle`, either parse them when taking from JSON by calling `JSONObject#getLong` or parse them in other Activity with [`Long#parseLong`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#parseLong(java.lang.String))

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are trying to parse the data from Taipei city's Youbike service on the Android platform. I wrote such piece of code already, and it's open source (License AGPL).

You might want to take a look at my source code and find out how to do:
https://github.com/le-moulin-studio/bike-friend/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/lemoulinstudio/bikefriend/ubike/YouBikeStationProvider.java